# Repeating the value in a df column by a specified amount, and concatenating integer count to repeated values

Tags: r, dataframe, seq, rep

I would like to use R to create an `expanded_df` from a `template_df`, where each row is repeated by a number of times specified in a separate column in the `template_df`, and an integer count is concatenated to the ID column in the `expanded_df`, specifying the number this row has been repeated in the `expanded_df`.

I would like this count to start at 600 for each ID class.

E.g., `template_df`:

```
Initial_ID  Count
a           2
b           3
c           1
d           4
```

`expanded_df`:

```
Expanded_ID
a-600
a-601
b-600
b-601
b-602
c-600
d-600
d-601
d-602
d-603
```

Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `uncount` to expand the rows and then get the `rowid` (of the 'Initial_ID' to `paste` after adding 599

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
template_df %>% 
   uncount(Count) %>% 
   transmute(Expanded_ID = str_c(Initial_ID, 599 + rowid(Initial_ID), sep = '-'))
```

-output

```
 Expanded_ID
1        a-600
2        a-601
3        b-600
4        b-601
5        b-602
6        c-600
7        d-600
8        d-601
9        d-602
10       d-603
```

---

Or using `base R` with `rep` and `paste`

```
data.frame(Expanded_ID = with(template_df, paste0(rep(Initial_ID, Count), "-", 
       599 + sequence(Count))))
```

-output

```
   Expanded_ID
1        a-600
2        a-601
3        b-600
4        b-601
5        b-602
6        c-600
7        d-600
8        d-601
9        d-602
10       d-603
```

#### data

```
template_df <- structure(list(Initial_ID = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), Count = c(2L, 
3L, 1L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

template_df %>% 
  group_by(Initial_ID) %>% 
  slice(rep(1:n(), each = Count)) %>% 
  mutate(row = 600 + row_number()-1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  transmute(Expanded_ID = paste(Initial_ID,row, sep = "-"))
```

```
   Expanded_ID
   <chr>      
 1 a-600      
 2 a-601      
 3 b-600      
 4 b-601      
 5 b-602      
 6 c-600      
 7 d-600      
 8 d-601      
 9 d-602      
10 d-603
```